# Database doesn't appear after executing Code-First code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am running the code below to learn code-first workflow. The code perfectly compiles and runs. I think that the database is created because I can see previous entries when I run the code. But I can't see the database on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. When I refresh, the new database and tables. I can see the database on Server Explorer on Visual Studio Either. Why is that? How can I see that created database? Here is the code :

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new BloggingContext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter a new name for a new blog");
                var name = Console.ReadLine();

                var blog = new Blog { Name = name};
                db.Blogs.Add(blog);
                db.SaveChanges();

                var query = from b in db.Blogs orderby b.Name select b;

                Console.WriteLine("all blogs in database : ");

                foreach(var item in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                }

                Console.ReadLine();

            }

        }
    }


    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
       public virtual List<Post> Posts {get; set;}

    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }

     }



    public class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the connection string to the database explicitly, then you will know where the connection is actually made:

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext() : base("ConnectionStringName")

    // ...
}
```

And add a connection string to your config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Server=ServerName; Database=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Replace ServerName and DatabaseName with values on your machine

Comment: is the name of the config file "App.config" ?

Comment: If you are using web application then the file is App.config, if you are using web application then it is Web.config

Answer (score 0):

Check your config file, there should be a connection string entry. If this is pointing to your sql server instance then you will be able to see the database in your sql server management studio.

If the connection string is not pointing to your sql server instance, then the database will be created locally, check your project folder.